# How can I clear app data between test suites using Espresso and Junit?

Tags: junit, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have a class that runs various test suites. Every subsequent test suite fails because the app state isn't cleared between test suites. I do not want to use Android Orchestrator because that clears data between every test, I only want to do it between suites.

I have some code already which may clear data but no tests run after it is called so I'm at a loss currently.

```
@RunWith(Categories::class)
@Categories.IncludeCategory(RegressionTests::class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses( AuthenticationTests::class,
    AuthenticationInvalidTests::class,
    CreateAccountTests::class,
    AccountSecurityTests::class,
    CountrySelectionTests::class
)

// Run this class to run regression tests
class RegressionTests {
    // Clear app data between test suites
    companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val resource: ExternalResource = object : ExternalResource() {
            
            override fun after() {
                    val context = getApplicationContext<Context>()
                    val runtime = Runtime.getRuntime()
                    runtime.exec("pm clear ${context.packageName}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```